# How to 'partially' specialize member methods?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```
template<class T, bool isOrdered>
class Vector
{
public:
    int Find(const T& t); // Return its index if found.

    // Many other methods.
};
```

There are two versions of `Find` depending on the `true` or `false` of `isOrdered`. There is no partial specialization for member methods (`class T` is not specialized). My question is to how to specialize them? Thanks.

Comment: Omit the template argument u want to specialize, and put it after the vector

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for member functions.

Comment: You have to specialize the whole class, however in your case it seems like an if statement would suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use overload on `std::integral_constant`:

```
template<class T, bool isOrdered>
struct Vector {
   int find(const T& t) {
       return find_impl(t, std::integral_constant<bool,isOrdered>());
   } 
   int find_impl (const T& t, std::true_type)  {return 1;}
   int find_impl (const T& t, std::false_type) {return 2;}
};
```